# How set a filter before i red excel file vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have one excel with 90.000 rows, but when i filter my Column "H1" by "Sample Shop", i have 2000 rows. I want to read 2000 rows not 90000. How set a filter before i read excel file in vb.net?
My code is:

```
 Do While currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Nothing
If workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0 Then
                Name = currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
                DataSo = currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 33).Value
                Try
                    Dim Conv As Double = Double.Parse(DataSo)
                    Variable = DateTime.FromOADate(Conv).ToString("MMMM/dd/yyyy")
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try

                Data1 = Convert.ToDateTime(BOX_Data1.Text)
                Data2 = Convert.ToDateTime(BOX_Data2.Text)

                If (currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 4).Value) = "Completed" And (currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 8).Value) = "RBT SAMPLE SHOP" Then

                    If Variable >= Data1 And Variable <= Data2 Then

                        If currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 35).Value <> Nothing Or currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 35).Value = "0.00" Then
                            'a = String.Format("{0:N2}", Double.Parse(a))
                            a = a + currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 35).Value
                            x1 = x1 + 1
                        End If
                        If currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 38).Value <> Nothing Or currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 38).Value = "0.00" Then
                            'b = String.Format("{0:N2}", Double.Parse(b))
                            b = b + currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 38).Value
                            x2 = x2 + 1
                        End If
                        If currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 41).Value <> Nothing Or currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 41).Value = "0.00" Then
                            'c = String.Format("{0:N2}", Double.Parse(c))
                            c = c + currentWorksheet.Cells(i, 41).Value
                            x3 = x3 + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a similar code:

```
Dim oledbConnectionString As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
    & "DATA SOURCE=YourExcelFilePath.xls;" _
    & "EXTENDED PROPERTIES='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'"

Dim oledbConn As New OleDbConnection(oledbConnectionString)
oledbConn.Open()

Dim oledbCommand As OleDbCommand = oledbConn.CreateCommand()
oledbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * " _
    & "FROM [YourExcelSheetName$] " _
    & "WHERE [F8] LIKE @filter + '%'"

oledbCommand.Parameters.Add("@filter", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "sample shop"

Dim oledaXLSDaCaricare As New OleDbDataAdapter(oledbCommand)

Dim dtTest As New DataTable

Try
    oledaXLSDaCaricare.Fill(dtTest)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Try

oledbConn.Close()
oledbConn.Dispose()
```

Some notes:

- `HDR=N`o indicates that the first row doesn't contains column names; maybe you have to change it in `HDR=Yes`
- `[F8]` is a reference to the eigth column in the sheet, so `H` column

Comment: I don't need to put my values in datatable, i need to read all before i filter all rows.